# Converting stereo file to mono but preserving peak and RMS loudness

Tags: ffmpeg, data-conversion

I am converting stereo audio files to mono using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -ac 1 -ab 192k mono_$1
```

However, after conversion, the RMS and peak loudness levels are not the same.

```
Tests-iMac:auditions test$ ./rms.sh mono_test.mp3 
 mean_volume: -20.1 dB
 max_volume: -0.2 dB
 Peak level dB: -0.150201
 RMS level dB: -20.138039
 RMS peak dB: -10.650649
 RMS trough dB: -94.923318
 Flat factor: 0.000000
 Peak count: 2.000000
 Bit depth: 32/32
 Number of samples: 5800320
 Number of NaNs: 0.000000
 Number of Infs: 0.000000
 Number of denormals: 0.000000
Tests-iMac:auditions test$ ./rms.sh test.mp3 
 mean_volume: -22.9 dB
 max_volume: -2.9 dB
 Peak level dB: -2.896314
 RMS level dB: -22.883812
 RMS peak dB: -13.397327
 RMS trough dB: -95.943631
 Flat factor: 0.000000
 Peak count: 2.000000
 Bit depth: 32/32
 Number of samples: 5800320
 Number of NaNs: 0.000000
 Number of Infs: 0.000000
 Number of denormals: 0.000000
```

The first ouput is the mono file which is technically louder than the stereo file, listed second. How can I preserve the peak and RMS values while also converting to mono? I have no issue scripting in order to obtain the stereo loudness values to pass to the mono conversion process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to reduce the volume by 2.7db with an audio filter.

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -ac 1 -af "volume=-2.7dB" -ab 192k mono_$1
```

Comment: Why -2.7dB? Just because the example in the question results in a mono file which is 2.7dB too loud? Or is it always 2.7db too loud if one uses this kind of conversation?: `ffmpeg -i $1 -ac 1 -ab 192k mono_$1`

Comment: I believe this file in particular was 2.7db and don't believe that is an inherent number from the process.

Comment: The factor should probably be -2,97 dB because this is the result of 20*log10(0,71) with cos(45deg) = 0,71. Assuming the left and right parts are both coming from a 45deg angle to the listener.